# is there any where in sys directory that says which pcie slot device is plugged into

Tags: filesystem, pcie, dmidecode

I am looking for sys directory exported info for which slot number the pcie device occupy on motherboard. Is it possible sys directory or proc directory. Initially I tried dmidecode but it seems like the device in question is not present in SMBIOS info and that device not found with dmidecode. So Is it possible to look at sys directory or some where else for occupancy of slot by specific pcie device. in lspci -vvv | grep ' VGA ' device is detecting correctly but I could not tell which slot it occupy on motherboard pcie slots because dmidecode not showing any info on device.

The device is Nvidia GPU pcie. But my bios info using dmidecode -t 9 not giving me any info about that device. I even checked the code of DMIdecode. And that device is nowhere  in SMBios structures. Means the firmware for The device not wrote anything in SMBios. May be this is normal for closed source devices that dmidecode can't find those buses and device types. So I like to know is there any way I can find matching slot-pcie bus pair info

Comment: Hey no matter how many times I read this I just cant make any sense of it. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @David I need info on which motherboard slot pcie device is plugged into I am using Nvidia Gpu pcie device.  In dmidecode it does not show that device. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Maybe edit the question to make that more clear?

Comment: lspci -v -s dev  should give you the Physical Slot on line 3 of the output.

Comment: @ubfan1 does lspci -v -s command fetches info about slots similar to dmidecode? Can u tell means does the slot info also comes from bios entry

Comment: dmidecode does give an ID, which might be the slot.  Can't tell on my system, which has a PCI adapter plugged into the expresscard slot.  The lspci gives the card (GPU) as in physical slot 1, and the dmidecode gives the expresscard as ID 1 (no GPU listed).

Comment: @ubfan1 what is ID there is type `and the dmidecode gives the expresscard as ID 1 (no GPU listed).`